# Why is the execution time for present? twice as long as visible? in ruby/watir?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

After reading several web pages including [Testing by Justin Ko](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/checking-for-an-element-exists-visible-present/) which says

- exists? – Returns whether this element actually exists.
- present? – Returns true if the element exists and is visible on the page
- visible? – If any parent element isn’t visible then we cannot write to the element. The only reliable way to determine this is to iterate up the DOM element tree checking every element to make sure it’s visible.

From that

1. I would predict that exists? would be the fastest, because it only checks to see if the element exists.
2. That present? would be the 2nd fastest as it checks for existence and for visibility.
3. That visible? would be the slowest because (as I read it) it also has to iterate up the DOM element tree.

Simply checking one element sounds like constant-time while iteration sounds like linear-time.

I happened to be running some time tests and thought it would be interesting to time the above methods as well.  One of my predictions is wrong.

exists? is fastest; coming in just slightly faster than visible?
However, present? is about twice as slow as visible?

I tried calling the methods in a different order and also enclosing them in a 1.upto(10) loop to average out the times.  Same results.

Something is happening here that I don't understand and I'd like to understand.  Anyone know why present? takes about twice as long as visible?  Or at least have a hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense that present? is the slowest because it checks for existence **AND** for visibility.

https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/6212504320559a90966052506c5e9e26b7d16533/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb#L406

```
def present?
  exists? && visible?
end
```

It would make sense that it would take as long as exists? and visible? combined.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Great answer.  That information helps me in ways that I didn't expect.